# DejaVu warrning using Pure Data

Tags: puredata

Can you tell me what to do to resolve this warning? I have installed Pure Data 0.47-1

WARNING: Font family 'DejaVu Sans Mono' not found, using default (courier)
 pddp/dsp
... couldn't create

Comment: Installing that font might help. It has free license.

Comment: I have the same problem on Ubuntu though all Dejavu family fonts are installed. It happens only when launching pd from shell.

Answer (score 0):

Install the [DejaVu](https://dejavu-fonts.github.io/Download.html) font and the warning will disappear.